# Add drive to Ubuntu. Mount to apache www folder?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I'm in desperate need of more space to my webserver(Ubuntu). I have manage to install a new drive and mounted it to '/media/newdrive'.

Now I don't know what to do..

What I want to do is put all my websites media files located in my apache path: (/home/adminuser/website/mywebsitename/public_html/archive) to my new drive.

So I thinking maybe instead I can mount the new drive to '../public_html/archive' and add user ownership to www-data. If that works, then I don't need to change any path in my server files.

Is this a good idea or even possible?

Comment: You need to modify your apache2.conf file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is certainly possible to mount a drive to wherever you like in the filesystem (see @CommuSoft's answer), it would seem to me that to do so would be a little confusing, particularly if you are mounting drives to someone's home directory.

I would suggest using a [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) from the desired directory to the location in which the drive is mounted (which could be in `/media` or `/mnt` for example). Then you could configure apache to `FollowSymLinks` (which it does by default anyway) and it should just work.

If you adopt this strategy then you don't have to use the entire of the partition on the drive for web-available files, because you can symlink to a directory within the drive.

Answer (score 2):

Say you want to mount a drive (lets call it `X`) on a folder `f`, you can simply use the command:

```
mount /dev/X f
```

So what you need to do is:

1. Figure out how the device is listed in `/dev/` all devices (keyboards, RAM memory,...) are listed there, mounted (if applicable) or not.
2. Copy all data that was originally located at `f` to the root of your drive.
3. Unmount it
4. make a directory `f` back:

   mkdir -p f
5. mount it with `mount`.

---

Since you are working with a server, it is of course annoying to execute this procedure yourself every time you boot the machine. As @gandaliter points out, in that case, you better add the add a line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/X    f    ntfs    defaults    0    2
```

With `/dev/X` the device to mount, `f` the folder where to mount it, `ntfs` the type of the file system (perhaps another type), `defaults` the optional additional flags you would give with `mount`, `0` the fact that no backup is made and `2` the priority (`2` for all filesystems that are not root).

Comment: Perhaps you could explain how to add the entry to `fstab` too, so that the drive is always mounted on boot.